# I’m trying to make a lever that can only be placed on certain blocks

Tags: minecraft, minecraft-commands

This is what I have now but I’ve tried multiple different things. I’m on The most recent Xbox bedrock edition.

Give **@p lever 1 0**

`{“can_place_on”;[“diamond_block”]}`

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 0):

As [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191637) suggests, I think you can use the command `give @p minecraft:lever 1 0 {CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:diamond_block"]}` for this